# Inserting ASCII character using shell script

Tags: python, shell, ascii

I want to insert a copyright symbol in the comment for a Python file using shell script,

I used the following code for it,

```
echo -e "# \xc2\xa9 Copyright ABC" | cat - file.py > temp.py
```

but when I try to run the temp.py it throws the following error:

```
Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file 'temp' but no encoding declared
```

I want to insert the symbol using the ASCII code for it, which is 184. 
How do I do it using shell script?

Answer (score 1):

By writing it this way, you've overwritten the shebang. Try:

```
{ echo "#!/usr/bin/env python"; 
  echo -e "# \xc2\xa9 Copyright ABC"; 
  cat file.py; } > temp.py
```

Comment: But I do not want any other line written into my file. Is there any other way?

Comment: @user3101795: Do you execute the script as `python temp.py` or as `./temp.py`? Only in the latter case could this answer solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just paste the ASCII literal into your shell script?

echo -e "# © Copyright ABC" | cat - file.py > temp.py

Answer (score 0):

What about specifying the encoding on the first line, then add the ascii character

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Your coment with ascii characters
```